# SQL query with count aggregate

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to returns the cities in California and their install rate (users who installed the app out of the users who had an activity), ordered from the highest rate to the lowest?
Table name = Events

```
SELECT location, COUNT(*) AS num_of_installs
FROM data_mapping.Events
WHERE location LIKE '%California' AND event_type='install'
GROUP BY location
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sere about you question, but you can use `window functions` for calculate rate. Please check next query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    location, 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY location) AS location_installs,
    COUNT(*) OVER () AS num_of_installs,
    (COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY location))::numeric / COUNT(*) OVER () AS ratio
FROM Events
WHERE location LIKE '%California' AND event_type='install';
```

[SQLize - online SQL editor](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql12/3783c0725c0503baf16f88528b470ec3/)